# Array of ranges from min, max and number of ranges

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have a numeric range that I want to split in n ranges of equal sizes. Example:

```
[min, max], n

0, 10, 5 = [[0, 2], [2, 4], [4, 6], [6, 8], [8, 10]]
```

so I would like to build a function like:

```js
function buckets(range, bucketsNumber) {
  const [min, max] = range
  const bucketRange = (max - min + 1) / bucketsNumber
  const res = _.range(1, bucketsNumber).map((i) => {
    const start = (idx) => bucketRange * (idx - 1) + min
    const end = start(i) + bucketRange - 1
    return [start(i), end]
  })
  return res
}
```

The above function doesn't work because `buckets([0, 10], 5)` returns:

```js
[
  [ 0, 1.2000000000000002 ],
  [ 2.2, 3.4000000000000004 ],
  [ 4.4, 5.6000000000000005 ],
  [ 6.6000000000000005, 7.800000000000001 ]
]
```

What's wrong with that code?
`buckets` should works also with negative `range` values..

Comment: Why do you define `start` with some arithmetic rather than the previous `end`?

Comment: @mplungjan Looks like [this one](https://docs-lodash.com/v4/range/).

Comment: @mplungjan Yes, it's Lodash

Comment: @SebastianSimon good question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need lodash for this.

```js
bucket = ([min, max], bucketsNumber) => 
  Array.from({length: bucketsNumber}).map((el, idx, arr, step = (max - min) / bucketsNumber) => [min + idx * step, min + (idx + 1) * step])
  

console.log(0,10,5,bucket([0, 10], 5));
console.log(0,20,4,bucket([0, 20], 4));
console.log(-10,10,2,bucket([-10, 10], 2));
console.log(10,-10,4,bucket([10, -10], 4));
```

#### Edit

What this does:

- `[min, max]` in the [Arrow Function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)'s parameter list is [Array Deconstruction](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment). So `min` and `max` get the first (index `0`) resp. second element of the parameter array
- `Array.from({length: bucketsNumber})` creates an array of length `bucketsNumber`
  @see [Array.from](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from)
- This array will be mapped to a new array which is returned
- The mapping is done by a function that will return an array of arrays which each habe two numbers (`min + idx * step` and `min + (idx + 1) * step`). `min` is taking from the calling function (@cf [Closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures)), `idx` is the automatic index of the current element of the array through the `map` parameters, and `step` is calculated as [default parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters) in the function parameters (`step = (max - min) / bucketsNumber`)

Answer (score 1):

You could store the last right value and calculate the new value for the right side.

```js
function buckets([min, max], length) {
    return Array.from(
         { length },
         ((t, f) => (_, i) => [t, t = ++i === length ? max : min + f * i])
             (min, (max - min) / length)
    );
}

console.log(buckets([0, 10], 5));
```

Comment: I copied the `length` trick. Didn't knew that one

Comment: This version of the same idea seems simpler, without the internal IIFE: `const buckets = ([min, max], length, factor = (max - min) / length) => Array .from ({length}, (_, i) => [i * factor + min, (i + 1) * factor + min])`.  Of course it depends upon your tolerance for defaulted parameters.

Answer (score 0):

A simple recursion makes this pretty easy.  We calculate the end of the first bucket and then simply include `[min, end]` and recur on the remaining range and one fewer bucket, stopping when we have no buckets left to calculate.

```js
const buckets = ([min, max], n, end = min + (max - min) / n) =>
  n == 0
    ? []
    : [[min, end], ... buckets([end, max], n - 1)]

console .log (buckets ([0, 10], 5))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

I think we would need an example to handle your "negative range values."  This should work just fine with negative numbers, but if you mean something like "when `min` > `max`" then I think we need more information.

Answer (score -1):

Fixed the math. Thanks Scott

```js
let n=5, min = 2, 
next = min
const range  = Array.from({length: n}, (_, i) => [min * i, min * i + next]);
console.log(range)
```

Comment: `(_, i) => [min * i, min * i + next])`.  But this is really missing an input, because there's nothing to say that we start at `0` in general.